React navigation failing in React Native
I have a working app and project with React Native 0.72.1 with react navigation stack version 6.3.17, I have recently updated my app with 0.74.1 and suddenly I am getting error in my stack navigation with every screen as undefined, this is something weird & I am stuck. I am not sure if I need to updated my react-navigation package too for this? Please help
I have re-verified everything and the routes & screen both exists.
(https://i.sstatic.net/oTWnWGKA.png)

Checked if the screen exists or not
Checked if any typescript errors exists or not

Expecting to resolve this navigation issue, as it was working with older RN version.

can you provide the implementation of navigator ?

Changing it to newer version worked for me. Not sure why the older version still fails.

This doesn't answer the question as to why it isn't working with this version.
